# building historic table in hiveql with expiredate

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to build som kind of historic based on table 
with id and date

every date marks a change and the newest date the 
active one,

```
table

historic_trans
id  trans_date  
22  20170510 
22  20170502 
22  20170412
```

I want to build a historic table where the newest row
get marks at active by adding a expiredate column as '99991231'

I can easy find the active ones by

```
select id, max(trans_date)trans_date, '99991231' as Expiredate, 'yes' as active
from historic_trans 
where id = '22'
group by id
```

But i really need to set set the trans_date on the previous row
 in my inactive rows

```
id  trans_date   Expiredate active 
22  20170510    99991231    yes
22  20170502    20170510    no
22  20170412    20170502    no
```

So that expiredate reflects the change in the transaction

Can that be accomplished in pure hql/sql

i have been playing with following code but i am stuck in it

```
select historic_trans.id, historic_trans.trans_date,
    case when aktiv.Expiredate = '99991231' then aktiv.Expiredate
     else aktiv.Expiredate
    end as Expiredate
 from historic_trans 
 left outer join 
(
 select id, max(trans_date)trans_date, '99991231' as Expiredate, 'yes' as active
    from historic_trans 
    where id = '22' 
 group by id
) aktiv on aktiv.id = historic_trans.id and aktiv.trans_date =   historic_trans.trans_date
 where historic_trans.id = '22'
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Any reason for not using `date` type or at least ISO date format - `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: Well thats just have the data is received i would have no problem specifying ExpireDate in another format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  id
       ,trans_date
       ,lag (trans_date,1,date '9999-12-31') over w                     as Expiredate
       ,case when row_number () over w = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end     as active

from    historic_trans

window  w as (partition by id order by trans_date desc)
;
```

---

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+
| id | trans_date | expiredate | active |
+----+------------+------------+--------+
| 22 | 2017-05-10 | 9999-12-31 | yes    |
| 22 | 2017-05-02 | 2017-05-10 | no     |
| 22 | 2017-04-12 | 2017-05-02 | no     |
+----+------------+------------+--------+
```